# How to handle time out exception for self populated lists?

Tags: java, webdriver, testng

In my application, if I have to choose a University name , I just need to enter first three letters(not less than that) and it will generate a list of Universities. Now problem is sometimes it takes too long to generate the list and some times it doesn't generate the list at all and test fails with TimeOutException error. To handle this I have put it in a try-catch block, in catch I am clearing and reentering these letter in that univ box. But this makes code very ugly/bulky and doesnt ensure that putting inside catch wouldn't fail it.
So I wanted to loop it until success, it will keep on clearing and entering Univ letter until it populates the list. Why I want to do this , because it works in real time, manually(without WebDriver/Automation)?Is this the right approach,if NO, then how to fix this. If yes than, how to make it possible? 
I thought it could work like this:

```
#1 while (particular univ name is not visible)
#2 .clear
#3 .sendkeys first 3 letters
#4 wait till elelment is visble >> select >> pass
#5 if not visible >> repeat 2 & 3
```

I am using java to write my scripts on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is a correct approach.  It is a bug in your application.

If the entered data is incorrect and there is no matching list, then is the only case you should expect that results shouldn't be returned.  In that case, your verification is that : that results are not returned, which you can automate.

If you have valid data and the results are not returned, then I would take it as an application bug and talk to the dev.  You shouldn't ideally try to handle in code coz u r hiding a bug in that case.

Comment: umm..,you're right, but I cant report it, at it's not reproducible , it happens on intermittent basis. Sometimes there's no list, sometimes it comes very quickly. So if I want iterate it until I achieve success, how can I do it(however a discussion on this with dev is a sure thing)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion requires waiting period. Separate your .sendkeys with sleep in between. So the list can be correctly accumulated.
.sendkeys
sleep
sendkeys
sleep
sendkeys

Comment: That is no different but put so many try-catch block, I wanted to iterate it until I get success.

Comment: in case you want to do the loop, just set try catch until "condition" .isVisible == true. For sleep methode you can try catch it in one method (void), and use it as much as you want...

Comment: Thanks all. I thought that this approach is not right and discussing here i would get better ideas. But I iterate until success.